# Exchange 2003 with C# smtpclient

Tags: c#, smtp, exchange-server-2003

I am currently trying to use SmtpClient to send an email with exchange 2003. Using the code below it will not send an email, but it does not throw an exception which i assume means it is making a connection to the exchange server because. Also for the server setting I tried mail.server.com as well as the IP address and it still does not throw an exception.

```
        public static void emailTest()
    {
        string fromEmail = @"me@me.com";
        string ToEmail = @"me@me.com";          
        string body = "C Stuck Batches"; 
        string subject = "C Stuck Batches"; 

        try
        {
            SmtpClient MyMail = new SmtpClient("x.x.x.x");
            MyMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            MyMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            MyMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"domain\user", "password"); 

            MyMail.Send(fromEmail, ToEmail, subject, body);
            MessageBox.Show("Sent", "SENT", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception", "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        } 
    }
```

I have read through several other problems, but as far as I could tell most others were getting some sort of exception or timeout. Since this appears as though it connects I am not sure what the issue is. Would it throw an exception if it were unable to access the server? If I throw a different IP into the server it will throw an exception.

Also I have tried both the IP of the server and mail.xx.com and it will not throw an exception with either but if I put any other addresses it will fail.

Thanks in advance for anyhelp!

Comment: does domain\user have permission to send as me@me.com?

Comment: @RandomUs1r Yes I have used the domain user associated with the account as well as administrator.

Comment: That is by far the most common issue, I'd maybe fire up a VM and try logging into outlook with the domain account you're using and seeing if you can add and send the mailbox to be absolutely sure.  Other things that can go wrong... try specifying the port as the 2nd argument of smptclient, you can try seeing what the exchange server logs say.  Your code does look correct though.

Comment: @RandomUs1r - Thanks for your help. I added the port to no avail. I have tried using my personal domain account as a test, which works correctly with outlook and I still cannot get the application to send.

Comment: what happens when you add the machine you're sending from to the relays list?  when you say your own account, are you trying to send as yourself as well?  Also, what happens when you remove your deliverymethod line?

Comment: @RandomUs1r This machine was already on the list and there was no change. When referring to my acocunt, one of the tests I did was log into my domain account and use my email/domain info in the code, so that way when the application tried to send the email it was running on the same profile as the email it was trying to use. Nothing changes when I removed that line

Comment: Just to be double sure... the domain account is listed in the location referred to here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2005/01/07/348596.aspx right?  I've set this up a few times myself and there's only a few vectors to approach this problem outside of incorrect server name type errors.

Comment: THis was not the fix however, you lead me to the correct fix. I had given the machine access to smtp by IP, but not the profile. Once I gave the profile access in Exchagne System Manager Everything began working. I assumed that the domain admins would have access by default due to another application that uses smtp to send emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues i had was that even the domain admins did not have access to the SMTP relay. I had to make sure the user was authenticated in the SMTP relay. Regardless of the fact the authenicating user was the same as the email adress used, that user did not have access. Once corrected it was able to send without issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Exchange server set up to relay mail from your IP address? If it isn't, mail may be "silently" discarded without throwing an Exception (the client is connecting correctly, it's the back end that's discarding the email)

[This link](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/how-to-setup-windows-2003-and-exchange-2003-smtp-relaying.12411/) provides more information on how to configure relaying on Exchange 2003 (I'm assuming "eSupport" would equate to your application in this example i.e. the IP of the machine running your code).

> Log into Exchange 2003 server (192.168.5.25 in my example above) and start Exchange System Manager.
>
> Expand the organization_name object, and then expand the Servers node. Expand the server_name object of the server on which you want to control mail relay, and then expand the Protocols node.
>
> Expand the SMTP node, right-click the virtual SMTP server on which you want to control mail relay, and then click Properties
>
> Click Relay.
>
> In the Relay Restriction dialog box, several options are available. The Only the list below option is enabled by default; the list below this option is empty.
>
> Click Add. Enter the IP address of the server running eSupport (192.168.5.80 in my example above).
>
> In the Relay Restrictions dialog box, click OK.
>
> Click Apply, and then click OK in the Default SMTP Virtual Server Properties dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I checked and it is already set to allow this machine access to the smtp relay.